# Auth0 sms mfa authentication redirects to login page

Tags: javascript, c#, sms, auth0, multi-factor-authentication

I am new in auth0 and I am trying to enable sms MFA on a angularJS application that has a C# API.

We are currently using Auth0-lock 11 and and we are using the universal login. Without the MFA the application authenticates users properly and redirects to the application from the login screen.

But after I enable MFA, after the user enters their username and password and click login, the verification code screen shows, then the user enters the 6 digit pin and clicks the login button to verify.

And then instead of continuing on to the application the user is redirected to the login screen again.

Is there something that I am not catching with code that I am supposed to catch and use to authenticate the MFA?

As far as I think, I think that API call to authenticate the sms code are done by the Auth0-lock UIs (I might be mistaken).